# Access Field Not Refreshing

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2003

To start, I am using Access 2003 and have a similar project that works correctly that I designed.

I am stumped as to why a particular field will not change dynamically like every other field until I "refresh".

Currently I have a task list that lists all items that need to be works. Containing a Status: New, Open, Closed; The account number, person who is working it and more.

The tasklist is just a form with a subform with a datasheet view that opens the task when you double click it. If a user opens a task, that task will be locked until they move on. If any information that is viewed in the task list is changed, it dynamically updates, all but the Status (which really is the most important) until the user manually refreshes it.

Does anyone know what I need to look for that would cause this? The Status is stored as an integer that joins with it's true value. I thought this may be the reason, however I have a similar tool I designed does not have this issue.

I've look into how they are joined, the code that changes this value, everything seems the same between the working and not working.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

**edit** any fields that are JOINED, do not seem to dynamically update until I hit refresh. However, the other database has this working. What am I missing that is different between them.

Comment: I would suggest adding the code to your question where you think it might create the issue. This way it can be checked if something might be wrong

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I changed the object displaying the field from a textbox to a combobox, showed two columns with widths 0";1" and it works.